# what is use of sqlserver analysis services in SQLSERVER2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the use of sqlserver analysis services in sqlserver2005?

where should we use analysis services? how to configure these analysis services?

Answer (score 2):

You can find everything you need to know about SQL Server Analysis Services on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175609(SQL.90).aspx

Once you have digested the material, feel free to pose specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

SSAS is a collection of data warehouseing technologies to help push reporting technologies.  one of the major things ssas has is cubes.